# How should I transactionally persist an entity and publish its events?

Tags: events, architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design, event-driven

In this simple example, we load an entity from a repository, ask it to perform an operation and then insert the result (a new state) through the repository again.

```js
const doSomething = (personDao: PersonRepository) => (personId: PersonId) => {
  const person = personDao.findBy(personId)
  const newState = person.doSomething()
  personDao.insert(newState)
  return newState
}
```

However, if `person.doSomething()` not only returns its new state, but also a domain event, how am I supposed to persist the state and publish it transactionally?

```js
const doSomething = (eventPublisher: EventPublisher) => (personDao: PersonRepository) => (personId: PersonId) => {
  const person = personDao.findBy(personId)
  const [event, newState] = person.doSomething()
  personDao.insert(newState)
  eventPublisher.publish(event)
  return newState
}
```

That is, if

`personDao.insert()`

goes through and if

`eventPublisher.publish()`

does not, then the insertion should be rolled back. Making sure events are published is essential since other applications will need it.

## Possible solution

`PersonRepository` should persist the person and also the events in a separate table.

Something (?) should poll the `events` table to check for new events, and then send it to a message broker.

I'm not sure how feasible this idea is.

And, what if I am using a database that does not support transactions, such as Cassandra? Or MongoDB, in which case I would have to store the events inside the `Person` document? I am not using either, but just a thought I had.

Thanks.

Comment: "PersonRepository should persist the person and also the events in a separate table." That's the usual answer.  See: https://vimeo.com/111998645

Answer (score 2):

There are two broad solutions to this:

- First is the *transactional outbox* pattern, in which you persist the domain events and the updated entity in one atomic transaction.  The events can be tracked by polling or via a change-data-capture to feed a message broker.
- Second is the *event sourcing* approach in which you just persist the events (domain events but also, potentially, events which are "implementation details" of your representation).  The events can then be used to construct the entity; as an optimization, another process can poll/change-data-capture the events and update a snapshot of the entity (in which case, the process of reconstructing an entity is load the latest snapshot (which includes a version) and then apply the events after that version to the snapshot).

Because your events and your snapshots/entities are different data models, for datastores which are table-oriented, you will almost certainly want to have those be in different tables; for datastores which are more stream-oriented, likewise you'll want those in separate streams.  Accordingly, the suitability of a transactional outbox approach rests on the ability to atomically write to multiple tables/streams.  Event sourcing doesn't have that requirement.

I would characterize the approach of writing an entity and the events together as event sourcing (where the events happen to include the snapshot).  If going that route, I would then have a consumer (fed by polling or by change-data-capture) demultiplex the paired events and snapshot.